# Do Tauriel and Kili find love in The Hobbit? Although Tauriel is not actually in the novel? Does anyone know this out of interest?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, elves, dwarves

There seems to be a love triangle brewing in the Hobbit Story. I have just been to see the second instalment of Peter Jacksons (remarkable) interpretation of The Hobbit and I am intrigued as to where the story seems to be heading.

Forgive me as I have not read The Hobbit to date but now I feel as if I have to!!

So, my question is this - do they actually fall in love, or because of the fact that they are not the same species, they cannot?

Comment: Are you asking how the book ends?

Comment: No, I am not. As it seems that Tauriel is not actually in the book. From what I gather, she is a new addition?

Comment: Since you're not asking if Tauriel is in the book, and we don't have advance copies of Jackson's script, this question seems unanswerable. Can you please edit it to be something we might be able to answer?

Comment: Hmm, as someone that has not actually read the book (apologies for that) then the question is straight forward.
However, I do appreciate your comment, and I will amend the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tauriel isn't in the book, she is a new character introduced in The Desolation of Smaug. So we can't answer this question.

Comment: Hmm, agreed. I have just begun some research here and realised that she actually is not in the book????

Comment: It's an easy question to answer: No, they do not fall in love in the novel because they don't meet.

Comment: Good point. However, in Peter Jackson's interpretation, they are almost holding hands at one point and Kili states that 'it cannot be you I have seen in the star light' or something to that effect whilst attempting to recover from the poison that runs through his blood from the Orc arrow?

Comment: So, if she is not in the novel, I cannot understand the introduction in to the film adaptation if honest.

Comment: Well, I don't see how that could possibly work without further changing the events from the book.   Grr, it didn't take my spoiler markup tag, so I've deleted the spoiler. You can see it in my edits, though.